# File upload issue with cross domain Issue Angularjs + Web API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to upload csv file from angular **POST** to **Web API post** but Eeb api return below error

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:89/WebService/Upload. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://Application:90' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404."

**Note** : Normal post with JSON data working after doing cross enable in web api, **only issue with file upload .**

Answer (score 0):

This is because the server is not returning the **'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'** header with your **'localhost'** origin.

So this problem can be solved as follows:

- Add support for CORS at server side to allow your origin (localhost) to make requests.
- or by disabling the CORS in your browser, similar kind of problem is already discussed here also [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)